# Localized date (month and day) and time with NSDate

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdateformatter

I want to be able to get the local date and time for wherever my app is run, based on the iPhone configuration.  Specifically I need the date to be of format mm/dd or dd/mm (or dd.mm, mm.dd, dd-mm, mm-dd, etc) depending on the locale, and time is hh:mm.  Is this possible with some combination of SDK methods?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I believe the following code works for what I need:

```
NSString *dateComponents = @"yMMd";
NSString *dateFormat = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:dateComponents options:0 locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
NSArray *tmpSubstrings = [dateFormat componentsSeparatedByString:@"y"];
NSString *tmpStr;
NSRange r;
if ([[tmpSubstrings objectAtIndex:0] length] == 0) {
    r.location = 1;
    r.length = [[tmpSubstrings objectAtIndex:1] length] - 1;
    tmpStr = [[tmpSubstrings objectAtIndex:1] substringWithRange:r];
} else {
    r.location = 0;
    r.length = [[tmpSubstrings objectAtIndex:0] length] - 1;
    tmpStr = [[tmpSubstrings objectAtIndex:0] substringWithRange:r];
}
NSString *newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ H:mm", tmpStr];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:newStr];
NSString *formattedDateString = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Answer (score 13):

I have modified the code so that it just takes the date and time out of the NSDate object with no changes:

```
NSDate* date = [NSDate date];
NSString* datePart = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate: date 
                                                    dateStyle: NSDateFormatterShortStyle 
                                                    timeStyle: NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
NSString* timePart = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate: date 
                                                    dateStyle: NSDateFormatterNoStyle 
                                                    timeStyle: NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
NSLog(@"Month Day: %@", datePart);
NSLog(@"Hours Min: %@", timePart);
```

Comment: That works fine. However, if the localized date has the year first, then this code breaks, doesn't it?

Comment: True. Is there a localization that does such a thing? The problem is that we have no reliable way of determining which number is the year from the string. Your best bet would be to not try to modify what comes out of the DateFormatter... I have modified the code in my answer to do just that.

Comment: If you take a look at my code, the line that gets the date format is the secret.  That gives me the localized format: y/MM/d or d/MM/y or MM/d/y or whatever.  Once I get the y and the separator removed, I can use that string for the setDateFormat argument to the formatter, and get the appropriate localized date without the year.